# JQuery Event Method To Affect One Element of A Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to separate out an event method to effect just one specific element within a larger class.

Goal: When user changes value in input box for number of nights, the total price changes (only for that specific input). Currently, all classes are being altered simultaneously. I believe .find or .closest is the trick, but am unsure how to implement. here's the .js.

```
  //nights auto multiply price
$(".cashtotal").prepend("$");
$('.nights').on('keyup change', function() {
var nights = +$(this).val();
var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");
$(".cashtotal").text(nights * dailyPrice);
$(".nights-total").text(nights);
$(".cashtotal").prepend("$");
});
```

and an example from the html

```
<div class="col-md-4 socal tour panel panel-default" data-discount="99" data-daily-price="100">
                    <h2 class="title">Idlehour, Angeles National Forest</h2>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="description">A pleasant trail through red fir forest with access to different
                            lake basins and the Yosemite Creek watershed.</div> 

                            <div class="nightsnum">
                                <p>
                                    <label for="nights">Number of Nights</label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="number" value="3" class="nights">
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="total">
                            <p><span class="cashtotal">400</span><br> for <span class="nights-count">3</span> Nights</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You're already using `$(this).closest(".tour")`, so just chain it to `$(this).closest(".tour").find(".cashtotal").text(nights * dailyPrice);`

Comment: Hopely You did solve this issue. Adeneo has gived you the right direction to go

Comment: @adeneo thanks dude! worked. i'm unsure how comments are different from answers. but i want to select yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//nights auto multiply price

$(".cashtotal").prepend("$");

$('.nights').on('keyup change', function() {
  
  var $thisTour = $(this).closest(".tour");
  var nights = $(this).val();
  var dailyPrice = $thisTour.data("daily-price");

  $(".cashtotal", $thisTour).text("$" + nights * dailyPrice);
  $(".nights-total", $thisTour).text(nights);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- I can't seem to separate out an event method to effect just one specific element within a larger class.

Goal: When user changes value in input box for number of nights, the total price changes (only for that specific input). Currently, all classes are being altered simultaneously. I believe .find or .closest is the trick, but am unsure how to implement. here's the .js. -->

<div class="col-md-4 socal tour panel panel-default" data-discount="99" data-daily-price="100">
  <h2 class="title">Idlehour, Angeles National Forest</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="description">A pleasant trail through red fir forest with access to different lake basins and the Yosemite Creek watershed.</div>

    <div class="nightsnum">
      <p>
        <label for="nights">Number of Nights</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="number" value="1" class="nights">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
      <p><span class="cashtotal">100</span>
        <br>for <span class="nights-total">1</span> Nights</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 socal tour panel panel-default" data-discount="99" data-daily-price="200">
  <h2 class="title">Another forest</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="description">another tour.</div>

    <div class="nightsnum">
      <p>
        <label for="nights">Number of Nights</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="number" value="1" class="nights">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
      <p><span class="cashtotal">200</span>
        <br>for <span class="nights-total">1</span> Nights</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is worded in a way where the person giving the answer needs to interpret it.  This is my interpretation.  I am assuming that there are multiple tours.  When you change one tour it changes all the ".nights-total" and ".cashtotal" classes.  What you can do to solve this issue is use a context for the selector.  In this case it is the tour that is the container that is the context for each ".nights-total" and ".cashtotal" class.  If I have made the wrong assumptions please update your question in a clearer meaning.  Hope this helps.